# Issues with running R in a docker container for an AWS Lambda function

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, curl, terra

I'm trying to setup a containerized image with R to be used by an AWS lambda function. I installed R version 4.3.0 on the [public aws lambda image available](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-provided), I have a [custom runtime R script (to interact with lambda)](https://medium.com/geekculture/effectively-running-r-scripts-from-aws-lambda-functions-6af85caa1571), and a lambda function R script to process landsat images. Here is my current dockerfile

```
FROM ghcr.io/lambgeo/lambda-gdal:3.6 AS gdal

#aws image for lambda ECR image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2

ENV PREFIX /opt
COPY --from=gdal /opt/lib/ $PREFIX/lib/
COPY --from=gdal /opt/include/ $PREFIX/include/
COPY --from=gdal /opt/share/ $PREFIX/share/
COPY --from=gdal /opt/bin/ $PREFIX/bin/

#set gdal version
ENV GDAL_VERSION="$(gdal-config --version)"
RUN export GDAL_VERSION

ENV \
  GDAL_DATA=$PREFIX/share/gdal \
  PROJ_LIB=$PREFIX/share/proj \
  GDAL_CONFIG=$PREFIX/bin/gdal-config \
  GEOS_CONFIG=$PREFIX/bin/geos-config \
  PATH=$PREFIX/bin:$PATH

ENV R_VERSION=4.3.0

RUN yum -y install amazon-linux-extras && \
    yum clean all

RUN amazon-linux-extras install kernel-5.15 && \
    yum clean all

RUN yum -y install wget-1.14 && \
    yum -y install glib2-2.56.1-9.amzn2.0.3 && \
    yum -y install libssh2-1.4.3-12.amzn2.2.4 && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
    yum clean all

RUN yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
  && wget --no-verbose https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/centos-7/pkgs/R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && yum -y install R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && rm R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm \
  && yum clean all 

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/"

RUN yum -y install openssl-devel && \
    yum -y install openldap-2.4.44-25.amzn2.0.5 && \
    yum -y install libxml2-devel && \
    yum -y install libjpeg-turbo-devel && \
    yum -y install libpng-devel && \
    yum -y install fontconfig-devel && \
    yum -y install harfbuzz-devel && \
    yum -y install fribidi-devel && \
    yum -y install netcdf-devel && \
    yum -y install geos-devel && \
    yum -y install proj-devel && \
    yum -y install freetype-devel && \
    yum -y install libtiff-devel && \
    yum clean all && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/bin:/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/R/4.2.2/bin/:/opt/lib"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('aws.s3','curl','httr', 'jsonlite', 'logger', 'logging', 'terra', 'parallel', 'xml2'), INSTALL_opts=c('--no-docs', '--no-help','--no-html', '--no-multiarch', '--no-test-load'), dependencies=TRUE, repos=c('https://rspatial.r-universe.dev','https://cloud.r-project.org/','https://artifactory.wma.chs.usgs.gov/artifactory/r-cran-mirror/','https://RForge.net'))"

#copy scripts to working directory
COPY runtime.R bootstrap.R process_landsat_temp.R testFunction.R ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
RUN chmod 755 -R "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\ncd /var/task\nRscript runtime.R' > /var/runtime/bootstrap \
  && chmod +x /var/runtime/bootstrap

HEALTHCHECK NONE
```

I can get a simple test lambda function running when no additional packages are needed. But I can't run my more complex lambda function that requires several R packages ('aws.s3','curl','httr', 'jsonlite', 'logger', 'logging', 'terra', 'parallel', 'xml2').

There seems to be a problem with Installing the terra package and getting curl to work correctly with lambda. I need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH within the dockerfile to this to get the terra package to install but then curl doesn't work when I try to test the function.

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/bin:/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/R/4.3.0/bin/:/opt/lib"
```

This is my error when testing either my simple or complex function within the aws website interface

```
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
INFO [2023-06-08 13:36:57] Handler found: process_landsat_temp.process
INFO [2023-06-08 13:36:57] Using function process from process_landsat_temp.R
INFO [2023-06-08 13:36:57] Querying for events
ERROR [2023-06-08 13:36:59] Error in curl::new_handle(): An unknown option was passed in to libcurl
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : object 'event' not found
```

Installing R in the container, installs 2 versions of curl, and having libcurl/7.88.1 installed in the /bin/curl directory seems to be what is needed to get curl to work with lambda and I can run my simple function but this only works if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not defined (and then terra does not get installed)

```
bash-4.2# /opt/bin/curl --version
curl 7.73.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.73.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips zlib/1.2.7 nghttp2/1.42.0
Release-Date: 2020-10-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL UnixSockets
bash-4.2# /bin/curl --version
curl 7.88.1 (x86_64-koji-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.88.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips zlib/1.2.7 libidn2/2.3.0 libssh2/1.4.3 nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: 2023-02-20
```